# use Button to get text in EditText and Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I want to get the text from a EditText and Spinner at the same time, but when I choose a type other than All types, it changes to All types itself.

**My question is why Feature Flim changes to All Types by itself after I click send Button, is not how to get selected item in spinner.**

strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="country_arrays">
<item>All Types</item>
<item>Feature Flim</item>
<item>TV Series</item>
<item>Video Games</item>
</string-array>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
     />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
```

here is the function sendMessage in MainActicity.java:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "You have selected the book: " + String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);


}
```

I choose feature flim:

[image: I choose feature flim]

after I click send

[image: after I click send]

finally it shows:

[image]

Why it change to All types by itself? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the adapter and data within `sendMessage`. So, every time you click "Send", the `Spinner` is being repopulated, and thus ends up at position 0 again.

Instead, do the following:

First, place the following line in your class declaration:

```
private Spinner spinner = null;
```

Second, move these to `onCreate()` (or wherever you call `setContentView()`):

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); // Do not re-declare
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
            "You have selected the book: " + String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```

Third and finally, leave the following in your `sendMessage()` method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I would move
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
as a private field though, but this is just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the text in another way:

```
spinner.geItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
```

Comment: You mean in the public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)?

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected item of Spinner do as below:

```
Spinner mySpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner_Id);
mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```